# Jquery: Include head from external file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can anyone please help me to understand why I'm not able to append the HTML head to index.htm from an external file(header.htm)?

I'm using the following codes:

Index.htm:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head id="head">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<script>
  //window.location.replace('./Components/header.htm');
  $.get("./Components/header.htm", function(data) {
    //alert(1);
    $("head").append(data);
  });
</script>

</html>
```

header.htm:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>SAM Store</title>
<link rel="icon" href="./Static/Final-JPEG.jpg">
```

I'm able to successfully redirect from index.htm to header.htm

Comment: Hi, is `data` having right values ? Are you seeing any error inside browser console.

Comment: Hi Swati, thanks for the quick reply. I'm able to see that browser is giving cors error. I guess

_"file:///C:/Users/YashA/Desktop/SAM%20Store/Website/index.htm"_
 &
_"file:///C:/Users/YashA/Desktop/SAM%20Store/Website/Components/header.htm"_

are being considered as 2 different domains, how can I resolve this issue

Comment: You are running this in localhost  or not ? Your url should look like `http://localhost/...`

Comment: Don't run your project from the file system, create a local web server and run the project from there.

Comment: Thanks Swati & cloned, the suggestion has resolved my issue.